# Getting ClassNotFoundException while using Class.forName("com.actitime5.Testcases."+vriable);

Tags: java, class, classloader

I've been messing around with ClassLoaders in java recently, trying to run my automation script code which uses dynamic loading of classes and geting `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
##MyCode

package com.actitime5.frameworkengine;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.gmail5.Testcases.LoginLogout;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
public class Init {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
Init in=new Init();
String url=in.getConfigValue("url");
ExcelLibrary lib=new ExcelLibrary();
JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
int numberofTestcases=lib.getRowCont("Scenario");
System.out.println(numberofTestcases);
for(int i=1;i<=numberofTestcases;i++)
{String status=lib.getExcelData("Scenario", i, 1);
if(status.equals("yes"))
{String scriptnam=lib.getExcelData("Scenario", i, 0);
System.out.println("Sheet Name"+" "+scriptnam);
Class scriptToRun= Class.forName("com.gmail5.Testcases."+scriptnam);

core.run(scriptToRun);
}

}}

##Errors that i am getting :

1
Sheet Name LoginLogout   
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.gmail5.Testcases.LoginLogout   
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.gmail5.frameworkengine.Init.main(Init.java:24)
```

The class which I am trying to load is available in package: `com.gmail5.Testcases.*;`,but still it throws exception

Comment: Can you post the full code for `LoginLogout`? Also edit your question to show us how do you run this thing

Comment: Add code to print out the full name that you're passing to `forName`, so you can double-check that it's correct.  And temporarily edit in a replacement for the last two lines as `core.run(com.gmail5.Testcases.MyMissingClass.class);`, to assure that that works.  (If not, MyMissingClass is not properly located in the directory structure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class name has trailing whitespace.  Try `trim()`ming it off before attempting to load the class.

You can confirm this by replacing

```
System.out.println("Sheet Name"+" "+scriptnam);
```

with

```
System.out.println("Sheet Name"+" '"+scriptnam+"'");
```

I expect this will print out something like the following:

```
Sheet Name 'LoginLogout    '
```

When I clicked 'edit' to edit your question, I could see there was trailing whitespace after the class name in the stack trace and in your `Sheet Name` message.  (I didn't change anything in your question: I just used the Edit function to see the raw text of your question, and then clicked Cancel.)

Comment: Thanks luke you are right, there was a white space, i was getting this class name from a xlsx sheet and there was a white space after the class name.